# I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 36 -Volley library error -Android

Tags: android, spring-boot, sockets, websocket, android-volley

I googled a lot of times for this issue that I suffer but no article helped me to find a solution to this problem.

Description:

I used volley library for makes networking for my app android easier and most importantly, faster .. etc, initial thing I do is preparing volley library on my project then I used a link (this link from internet which provides me a JSON data) therefore everything worked successfully but when I used my server on my own computer (server is built by spring boot framework) my android application gave me this errors :

```
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
    (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/qtaguid: Tagging socket 36 with tag b842893200000000{3091368242,0} uid -1, pid: 31466, getuid(): 10219
I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 36
E/Volley: Error
```

please, any expert could help me with this problem because this issue doesn't let me complete my project.
I apologize if I made any mistakes on my writing cause English not my original language